# SAS Removing delimiters among dates

Tags: sas, delimiter

I am working in SAS with biological testing data that contains multiple possible testing and collection dates. I am interested in removing the numbering system of input data and choosing the most recent testing date. The most recent testing date is always the first date available, but sometimes that date is missing.

For example, the input for one record is `[1]04/04/2004[2]02/10/2002[3]2/02/2002[4]01/01/2001` and so on. Cases range from having 1 to 38 dates under the one variable. I am interested in removing the numbering system  in [] and choosing the most recent testing date. The most recent testing date is always the first date available.

I tried to use

```
var=substr(var, x,x)
```

however this poses a problem when the first date is blank.

I'm hoping I've explained that properly, please let me know if any clarification is needed.

Thank you!

Comment: So the values are already in a character variable? Or are you reading the values from a text file?  Please show an example what the value looks like when the first date is missing.

Comment: If that's a text file you should back up and re-read it differently. Then you can have each field in it's own column and work with it a bit easier.

Comment: @Reeza it is originally an excel file. I'm not sure how to split the columns up no matter which way I input the file? The way that is is presented is how it was pulled from the original source. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Tom thanks for your help! So the values are in a character already. Missing dates might look like [1][2][3][4][5]05/30/2021[6]04/34/2020. Eventually there is a value, but its far down the list, sometimes in the 10th place or higher. Your example is very helpful, thank you! I'm confused about the first var = function, though. Should I be copying in the true numbers there? This dataset has over 2000 cases included.

Comment: Do you care what the index is? Do you need to ever know the date is the 6th date? Or 5th date?

Comment: If you don't supply an actual dataset then we have to write our own code to create example data to show how the program could work.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the SCAN() function to pull out the first date strings. Stop when you get a valid date string.

First let's turn your examples into an actual dataset.

```
data have;
  input var $80. ;
cards;
[1]04/04/2004[2]02/10/2002[3]2/02/2002[4]01/01/2001
[1][2][3][4][5]05/30/2021[6]04/34/2020
;
```

Now we can use SCAN() with the M modifier to scan the string. You can use COUNTW() to know when to stop.

```
data want;
  set have ;
  do index=3 by 2 to countw(var,'[]','m') until (date ne .);
    date=input(scan(var,index,'[]','m'),mmddyy10.);
  end;
  format date yymmdd10.;
run;
```

Results:

```
                        var                            index          date
[1]04/04/2004[2]02/10/2002[3]2/02/2002[4]01/01/2001       3     2004-04-04
[1][2][3][4][5]05/30/2021[6]04/34/2020                   11     2021-05-30
```

Comment: Who can't remember April 34 ? That May have been the day I pleaded the 5th.

Comment: Star Wars day.  "May the 4th be with you."

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression pattern to locate a m/d/y construct within a string.

Example:

Presume only valid dates.  If an invalid datelike entry is encountered the date will be missing and the DATA Step will log `NOTE: Invalid argument to function INPUT ...`

```
data have;
  input var $80. ;
cards;
[1]04/04/2004[2]02/10/2002[3]2/02/2002[4]01/01/2001
[1][2][3][4][5]05/30/2021[6]04/34/2020
[1]12/32/2021
;

data want(label='First occuring date in var' keep=var newestdate);
  set have;

  date_rxid = prxparse ('#\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/(d{2}|\d{4})#'); /* presume m/d/y */

  start = 1;
  stop = -1;

  call prxnext(date_rxid, start, stop, var, position, length);

  if position then newestdate = input (substr(var,position,length), mmddyy10.);

  format newestdate date11.;
run;
```